# Как сохранить тело ответа каждого запроса в один файл (прогон коллекции Postman)

Tags: api, post, postman

Опыта работы с Postman 0. Понадобился по работе для получения данных (иных вариантов нет) посредством направления запросов. Языки программирования не знаю.

Условия: имеется тестовая коллекция на 300 запросов.
В теле ответа приходит информация в JSON.

Помогите, пожалуйста, объединить все в один файл с возможностью сохранить или скопировать.

Нашел с сети тестовый скрипт, который сохраняет результат в переменную коллекции. Пару раз скопировать вручную получилось, но при увеличении запросов Postman зависает. Если можно озвучьте решение проблемы как для умственно отсталого.

```
let responses = pm.collectionVariables.get('collectionResponses')

if(responses) {

responses = JSON.parse(responses);

} else {

responses = []

}

responses.push(pm.response.json());

pm.collectionVariables.set('collectionResponses', JSON.stringify(responses));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]